# Called from wrong thread using custom array adapter

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask, android-arrayadapter

I am trying to display a custom list view showing an image of a person and his name per row. The list of users is saved as a `JSON` in my project and the image is a `String` of the image url.

To get the actual image I tried parsing the JSON image while using `Async Task` as shown below:

```
public class PersonArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<PersonData>
{
    PersonCell personCell;
    PersonData personData;

    public PersonArrayAdapter(Context context, List<PersonData> objects)
    {
        super(context, 0, objects);
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        personCell = new PersonCell();

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.person_data, parent, false);

        personCell.imageView= (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageURL);
        personCell.usernameText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.usernameText);


        personData = getItem(position);

        personCell.usernameText.setText(personData.username);
        new LoadProfileImage(personCell.imageView).execute(personData.userImage);

        return convertView;
    }

     private class LoadProfileImage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
        ImageView bmImage;

        public LoadProfileImage(ImageView bmImage) {
            this.bmImage = bmImage;
        }

        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
            Bitmap bitmap=null;

            try {
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(personData.userImage).getContent());
                personCell.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return bitmap;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
        }
    }


    private static class PersonCell
    {
        TextView usernameText;
        ImageView imageView;
    }
}
```

But I get an error `android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.` So I guess the issue is that I can only run the AsyncTask in the Activity and not in the Adapter class. But I need to get the image in my Adapter class too...

How do I fix this?

Comment: very first things is you cannot modify ui in doInbackground thread [personCell.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);] 2. second things is the refrance to imageview seems to be not correct, try to use lazy loading

Comment: use smartimageview instead of asyntask here.may get the image from url.follow this url:http://loopj.com/android-smart-image-view/

Comment: @diva - if I cannot modify ui in the thread what should I do?

Comment: do it in postExecute method.

Comment: Try keeping personCell.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap); in postExecute method

Answer (score 1):

> So I guess the issue is that I can only run the AsyncTask in the
>   Activity and not in the Adapter class.

Of cause you can run the AsyncTask in the Adapter class. Your problem is that you access view in doInBackground() method which runs in another thread.

Loading image for `ListView` or something like this is not easy in android, I recommend you use `Volly` to do the work. Please refer to "8. Making Image request" here:

http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/

**Update:**

You problem may be solved simply by removing the line `personCell.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);` since you do not reuse the convertView, but your implementation may cause efficiency problem, I'm not sure whether this is what you truly want:

Comment: Ah so how should I proceed?

Comment: @user2456977 You'd better use lazy loading to do you work, see my update.

Comment: Is it possible to simply use a runnable somewhere?

Comment: thanks but I just ended up moving personCell.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap) to the postExecute method and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

Below is code snippet for adapter that loads the images asynchronously :

```
public class LazyImageLoadAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements OnClickListener{

    private Activity activity;
    private String[] data;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    public ImageLoader imageLoader; 

    public LazyImageLoadAdapter(Activity a, String[] d) {
        activity = a;
        data=d;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.
                            getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        // Create ImageLoader object to download and show image in list
        // Call ImageLoader constructor to initialize FileCache
        imageLoader = new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return data.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    /********* Create a holder Class to contain inflated xml file elements *********/
    public static class ViewHolder{

        public TextView text;
        public TextView text1;
        public TextView textWide;
        public ImageView image;

    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View vi=convertView;
        ViewHolder holder;

        if(convertView==null){

            /****** Inflate tabitem.xml file for each row ( Defined below ) *******/
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_row, null);

            /****** View Holder Object to contain tabitem.xml file elements ******/

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.text = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.text);
            holder.text1=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.text1);
            holder.image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.image);

           /************  Set holder with LayoutInflater ************/
            vi.setTag( holder );
        }
        else 
            holder=(ViewHolder)vi.getTag();


        holder.text.setText("Company "+position);
        holder.text1.setText("company description "+position);
        ImageView image = holder.image;

        //DisplayImage function from ImageLoader Class
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(data[position], image);

        /******** Set Item Click Listner for LayoutInflater for each row ***********/
        vi.setOnClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(position));
        return vi;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


    /********* Called when Item click in ListView ************/
    private class OnItemClickListener  implements OnClickListener{           
        private int mPosition;

       OnItemClickListener(int position){
             mPosition = position;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            MainActivity sct = (MainActivity)activity;
            sct.onItemClick(mPosition);
        }               
    }   
}
```

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer but turns out I just needed to move one line of code to the postExecute method

Comment: @user2456977 thats what i mentioned in earlier comment